# ChartJS data doesn't load unless I manually change the size of the graph

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, pinia

My Vue chart only loads if I manually change one of the values in my hardcoded options. It is coming from Pinia.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <canvas id="my-chart" width="90%" height="90%"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useDataStore } from "../stores/dataStore.js";
import { Chart, registerables } from "chart.js";
Chart.register(...registerables);

export default {
  name: "App",

  mounted() {
    const ctx = document.getElementById("my-chart");
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: [...this.dataStore.graphData.xAxis],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "24 Hour Balance (USD)",
            data: [...this.dataStore.graphData.yAxis],
            backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)"],
            borderColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 2)"],
            lineWidth: 1,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: false,
          },
        },
        responsive: true,
      },
    });
    myChart
  },
  setup() {
    const dataStore = useDataStore();

    return {
      dataStore,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Did you tried vue-chartjs? https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs#how-to-use

Comment: I also recommend using [template refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#template-refs) rather than querySelectors + use Options API if you already have some struggles, here's how: https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#usage-with-the-options-api

Comment: You had an additional `style` + funky `myChart` (still) in your `mounted` block btw.

Comment: the thing is if i edit any of my code. even if it's not specifically the chart.. it hotreloads and the chart is there... percectly .

Comment: Probably because the state is still bound to the query selector somehow. The idea here is to write proper code that works everytime rather than trying to understand some hacks while HMR is operating it's half-state updates.